# $S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x}$, show that $S(x)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ and $S(x)$ Differentiable on $[2,3]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I got the following question from a test:

$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x}$ show that $S(x)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ and $S(x)$ Differentiable on $[2,3]$

Maybe $S(x)$ is Differentiable on all $(0,\infty)$, but this is the question as given.

I tried to show by definition of continuous, but i never tried to do this on infinite series, so I got stuck.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n-1)^{-x}-(2n)^{-x} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{2n-1}^{2n} x t^{-x-1}dt$ converges absolutely. What is your guess for the derivative ?

Comment: @reuns                                                                                                          
I know that the series converges because it is a Leibniz series, but i don't see why it will converges absolutely, set $x=1$  and we will get a harmonic series.

Moreover, I don't really understand where it's leading me?

Comment: That's why I grouped the terms by two $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |(2n-1)^{-x}-(2n)^{-x}|$ converges. So what is your guess for the derivative, for the partial sum, and in the limit ?

Comment: @reuns                                                                                                      
I think that because you showed that it is an Integral of a continuous function then it is differentiable from the fundamental theorem of calculus. But that me thinking as kid who don't understand nothing.

Comment: Not at all. When you have a series you need to look at the partial sums. Let $S_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N (2n-1)^{-x}- (2n)^{-x}$. What is $S_N'(x)$ ?

Comment: @reuns I'm guessing  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty -ln(2n-1)(2n-1)^{-x}+ln(2n)(2n)^{-x}$.  I'm also don't know if it is allowed without showing uniform coverage or that because it is partial sum is allowed or that I'm wrong at all..

Comment: $S_N'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N -ln(2n-1)(2n-1)^{-x}+ln(2n)(2n)^{-x}$. Then you need to ask if $\lim_{N \to \infty} S_N'(x)$ converges. What is $x \in [2,3]$ ? What if $x \in (0,1]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x}$ converges to $S(x)$. Note 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{(2n-1)^x}-\frac{1}{(2n)^x}\right]. $$
Using the Lagrange Mean Value Theorem in $[2n-1,2n]$ for $f(y)=\frac{1}{y^{x}}$, one has
$$ \frac{1}{(2n-1)^x}-\frac{1}{(2n)^x}=\frac{x}{\xi_n^{x+1}},\text{ for some }\xi_n\in(2n-1,2n). $$
So, for $x\in[a,b]\subset(0,\infty)$,
$$ \frac{x}{\xi_n^{x+1}}\le\frac{x}{\xi_n^{x+1}}\le\frac{b}{(2n-1)^{a+1}}$$
and hence by the M-test, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x}$ converges uniformly in $[a,b]$ and hence $S(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$. Thus $S(x)$ is continuous is in $(0,\infty)$. For the second part, let
$$ f_n(x)=\frac{1}{(2n-1)^x}-\frac{1}{(2n)^x}. $$
First $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges to $S(x)$.
Note
$$ f_n'(x)=-\frac{\ln(2n-1)}{(2n-1)^x}+\frac{\ln(2n)}{(2n)^x}. $$
By the Lagrange Mean Value Theorem in $[2n-1,2n]$ for $g(y)=\frac{\ln y}{y^{x}}$, one has
$$ -\frac{\ln(2n-1)}{(2n-1)^x}+\frac{\ln(2n)}{(2n)^x}=-\frac{x\ln \xi_n-1}{\xi_n^{x+1}}, \text{ for some }\xi_n\in(2n-1,2n). $$
For $x\in[2,3]$ and $n>3$,
$$ 0\le\frac{x\ln \xi_n-1}{\xi_n^{x+1}}\le \frac{3\ln(2n)-1}{(2n-1)^{3}}\le\frac{3}{(2n-1)^3} $$
By the M-Test again, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x\ln \xi_n-1}{\xi_n^{x+1}}$ converges uniformly to some continuous function $F(x)$ in $[2,3]$. So $S(x)$ is differentiable $[2,3]$ and $S'(x)=F(x)$.